# In Ansible, can playbooks pass tags to other playbooks?

Tags: ansible

We have a "periodic" tag in our roles that is intended to be run at regular intervals by our Ansible box for file assurance, etc. Would it be possible to have a playbook for periodic runs that calls the other playbooks with the appropriate host groups and tags?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to execute an Ansible playbook "*with the appropriate host groups and tags*" is to run `ansible-playbook` executable. This is the only case in which all the data structures starting from the inventory would be created in isolation from the currently running playbook.

You can simply call the executable using `command` module on the control machine:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: ansible-playbook {{ playbook }} --tags {{ tags }}
```

You can also use `local_action` or `delegate_to`.

---

<sup>It might be that you want to include plays, or use roles, however given the problem description in the question, it's impossible to tell.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we ended up with: It turns out that tags and variables passed on the command-line are inherited all the way down the line. This allowed us to pass this on the command line:

```
ansible-playbook -t periodic periodic.yml
```

Which calls a playbook like this:

```
---
- name: This playbook must be called with the "periodic" tag.
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  any_errors_fatal: True
  tasks:
    - fail: 
      when: periodic not True

- name: Begin periodic runs for type 1 servers
  include: type1-server.yml
  vars:
    servers:
      - host_group1
      - host_group2
      - ...

- name: Begin periodic runs for type 2 servers
...
```

Our 'real' playbooks have `- hosts: "{{ servers }}"` so that they can be inherited from the parent. The tasks in our roles are tagged with "periodic" for things that need to be run on a schedule. We then use SystemD to schedule the runs. You can use cron, but SystemD is better IMHO. Examples can be provided upon request.

Comment: This way you include plays into a current playbook run. Taken literally, you are not answering your own question (which is because of vocabulary misuse, as I mentioned in small font in my answer).